# How do I prove that the set $\{0,1\} ^{\Bbb N} $is equivalent to the power set of natural numbers $P(\Bbb N)$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

At least I need a reference to some book.

Comment: I'm contemplating between closing this as a duplicate, or as lack of context.

Comment: For future reference, always make the body of the post self-contained. As it stands, your post should have been closed for a variety of different reasons (lack of context, unclear, duplicate). But seeing how someone jumped the gun and posted an answer, I figured a duplicate is the most appropriate. In the future, search first, search again, then when your third search came up empty, write a *proper* question.

Comment: It is my first post ever. I am unexperienced. Please show mercy :)

Comment: I would, in general, you should usually look around before you jump into the pool. There might be some rules against jumping in naked.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the mapping
$$f: P(\mathbb{N}) \to \{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$$
where $f(A) = (a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is the sequence of zeros and ones such that $a_n = 0$ if $n \notin A$ and $a_n = 1$ if $n \in A$. Now you can show that this is a bijection.

Comment: Thank for your response. Please show me why it is a bijection (I am very amateur in set theory).Thank you in advance !

Comment: Right *here* is where you follow Asaf's advice and read all the related answers that work through this question in detail, rather than asking someone to re-type them so that you don't have to click for 20 seconds. :)

Comment: Ok ! Got it! Thank you guys !!!